# Mysql Connection in Java: Access denied for user @ localhost

Tags: java, mysql

I'm not able to connect to the Database but I don't know why, since the username and password are correct and I'm able to connect through phpmyadmin locally.

```
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  // Setup the connection with the DB
  connect = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost/yerobot", "yerobot", "yerobot123");

  preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("select * from userdata");

  resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
  while(resultSet.next()){
    // do read rs
  }
```

Whenever I call for a connection, I get this stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'yerobot'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1086)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1750)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1290)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2502)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2320)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at yerobot.MySQLAccess.setZockerzaster(MySQLAccess.java:92)
    at yerobot.MyBot.zasterAction(MyBot.java:102)
    at yerobot.MyBot$1.run(MyBot.java:94)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Do you think all that code is relevant? Have you look up the error on the internet (or even this site)? I see a huge lack of effort.

Comment: i thought it would help to know the whole class. sorry

Comment: As Sotirios Delimanolis said, please make your code more concise and isolate the issue. Then it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: have you tried to set the password for both yerobot@localhost and yerobot@'%' ? Because MySQL differentiates local access and remote access passwords..

Comment: Well thank you Yudhi. setting up the user again with @localhost does work. i get now table xyz doesnt exist errors but ican work with that ow since connecting works. thanks !

Comment: @YudhiWidyatama Set your comment as the answer so that the OP can mark as answered and solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the password for both yerobot@localhost and yerobot@'%'

MySQL differentiates local access and remote access passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You got the username or password wrong, or it isn't authorised to connect from localhost. Simple as that. And perfectly clear from the exception.